# How could I implement the Tapered and Glyph edge representations in Android View?

Tags: android, data-visualization, graph-visualization

These novel edge representation methods are proposed in the paper 《An Extended Evaluation of the Readability of Tapered, Animated, and Textured Directed-Edge Representations in Node-Link Graphs》 by Danny Holten. However, they did not implement them in Android.

[Tapered edge represenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSplS.png)

[Glyph edge representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc5Ek.png)